# convert int to char without using ASCII

Tags: c++, c

How can i convert an int below 10 to a char for example :
5 -> '5'
**(convert int to char without using ASCII table)**

Comment: What do you mean "without using ASCII table"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since digits are always consecutive in a standard character set, you can write:

```
int number = 5;
int character = number + '0';

/* Here, character == '5' */
```

See, for instance, C11 standard.

> #### n1570, § 5.2.1 Character sets
>
> The 10 decimal *digits*: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
>
> [...]
>
> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

The same applies in C++.

> #### n3337, § 2.3 Character sets
>
> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

Comment: +1 This is the idiomatic way to convert integers to ascii.. `'0'` is the ASCII-offset for 0, so adding it to a number effectively converts it to ASCII

Comment: @MortenJensen s/number/digit/ though, to minimize risk of confusion.

Comment: @MortenJensen Recommend "idiomatic way to convert integer decimal digits to char".  Had the source code character set been in, say EBCDIC, this still works.  `'0'` is the offset for _any_ character set that conforms to C, not only ASCII.  Thus adding `'0'` does not necessarily convert 0 to ASCII, but to the character set of the source/execution.  ASCII is certainly very common - it's been many moons since I've exercised a non-ASCII, non-Unicode source code.

Answer (score 3):

If it is number 0-9 it is good to use:

```
int i = 5;
char ch = i + '0';
```

But probably the best option is to use itoa()

```
int i = 124;
char buffer[33];
itoa(i, buffer, 10);    //10 mean decimal.
```

Comment: `itoa` is nonstandard; better to recommend `snprintf`.  But it is possible that the OP is trying to *implement* a general binary-to-decimal converter, in which case telling them to use an off-the-shelf one isn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option

```
char c;
int x;
//...
switch ( x )
{
   case 1:
      c = '1';
      break;
   //and so on
}
```

And another:

```
std::map<int, char> mapping;
mapping[1] = '1';
//...

char c = mapping[4];
```

Comment: You could make it an array instead: `char mapping[] = "0123456789";` :P

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes not enough code :P

Comment: is this not a really in efficient way of doing this? even if it is below 10? especially when you have a itoa();?

Comment: @SD1990 the second one might be, I doubt the first one is. Profile it and see.

Comment: @SD1990 It is unbelievable but using `switch` conversion is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "without using ASCII table", but

```
int i = 5;
char c = i + '0';
```

will do what you want.  The character codes for `'0'` through `'9'` are guaranteed to be consecutive and in the proper order.